# How to prevent Pharo from executing a #startUp-Method of a class?

Tags: startup, smalltalk, pharo

I added a startUp-Method to one of my classes that immediatelly quits my image. Is there a way to prevent Pharo from executing that method so that I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is an issue of ongoing discussion. See [this post](http://forum.world.st/startup-errors-td3736966.html) on the Pharo mailing list.

Your only way to recover the image is to hack the VM, which I describe [here](http://forum.world.st/Fwd-Oops-I-put-a-halt-in-a-startup-method-tp3800729p4161823.html). If you go that route, use the stack VM instead of the JIT (the same thread explains why further down).